# Clarification of showing that something is an involution e.g. *-algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}):=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}:x_n\in\mathbb{C},\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|x_n|<+\infty\}$ .
Given by $(x^\ast)_n:=\overline{x_{-n}}$, we want to show that for $x \in \ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$, $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a $*-algebra$

claim:

1. $(x^\ast)^\ast=x$, $\forall x\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$.

\begin{equation*}
    (x^\ast)^\ast=(\bar{x})^\ast=\bar{\bar{x}}=x.
\end{equation*}
2. Let $x,y\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. Claim:
\begin{equation*}
    (ax+by)^\ast=\bar{a}x^\ast+\bar{b}y^\ast=\bar{a}\bar{x}+\bar{b}\bar{y}=\overline{ax}+\overline{by}=(ax)^\ast+(by)^\ast=(ax+by)^\ast.
\end{equation*}
3. $x,y\in\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}) $ claim:
\begin{equation*}
    (xy)^\ast=y^\ast x^\ast
\end{equation*}
But
$(xy)^\ast=(\overline{xy})=(yx)$ and then what???

Furthermore, I must show that $*$ is an isometry, which can easily be done if I show that
\begin{align*}
    ||x||^{2} \leq ||x^{*}x||,
\end{align*}
but I am not quite sure if that inequality holds $\forall x \in \ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z}) $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This inequality $\|x\|^2\le\|x^*x\|$ is not true, there are very easy counter-examples; also why even bother to show this when being an isometry simply means $\|x^*\|=\|x\|$ which is much simpler to show?

A counter example to the inequality you are trying to show: take $x=(x_n)$ with $x_n=0$ if $n\ne1,2$ and $x_1=1, x_2=-1$. Then $x^*=(y_n)$ where $y_n=0$ for all $n\ne-1,-2$ where $y_{-1}=1, y_{-2}=-1$. We have $\|x\|^2=(1+1)^2=4$. On the other hand,
$$\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}y_mx_{n-m}=x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}=\begin{cases}1, n=-1\\ 0,n=0\\-1, n=1\\ 0, \text{else}\end{cases}$$
so $\|x^*x\|=2<4$.

However, $-^*$ is indeed an isometry: let $x=(x_n)\in\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$. Then
$$\|x^*\|=\|(\bar{x_{-n}})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\|=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\bar{x_{-n}}|=\sum_n|x_n|=\|x\|.$$

Edit: A proof of the computation $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$. Let $x=(x_n)_n$ and $y=(y_n)_n$. We have $xy=\big(\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}x_my_{n-m}\big)_n$, so
$$(xy)^*=\big(\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\bar{x}_m\overline{y}_{-n-m}\big)_n$$
On the other hand,
$y^*=(\bar{y}_{-n})_n, x^*=(\bar{x}_{-n})_n$, so
$$y^*x^*=\bigg(\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}}\bar{y}_{-l}\bar{x}_{-n+l}\bigg)_n=\bigg(\sum_{\in\mathbb{Z}}\bar{x}_{-n+l}\bar{y}_{-l}\bigg)_n$$
so one should show that $\sum_{l}\bar{x}_{-n+l}\bar{y}_{-l}=\sum_m\bar{x}_m\bar{y}_{-n-m}$ which is clear after doing the change of variable in the left sum $k:=-n+l$: as $l$ ranges all over $\mathbb{Z}$, so does $k$ and thus
$$\sum_l\bar{x}_{-n+l}\bar{y}_{-l}=\sum_k\bar{x}_k\bar{y}_{-n-k}$$
as we wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate the counter examples as well I have been lacking concrete examples in this course so the more the merrier! Can I ask you if the way I was trying to show the three axiom holds e.g. showing that $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a *-algebra is somewhat on the right way?.

Comment: @Chengdu Yes, they are on the right way. You've almost completed the proof, all that's left is to show that $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$. You seem to be confused about this, but if you right down explicitly each step, you will see that this is straight forward: write what $xy$ is, then take the adjoint. On another line, write $y^*$, $x^*$ and write what their product is. You will see that the two things are equal

Comment: actually I gave it another shot, but I end up with the following which kind of makes me stuck:                                                                                $(xy) = (\overline{\overline{xy}}) = (\overline{yx}) = (yx)^{*}$ and                       $(xy)^\ast=(\overline{xy})=(yx)$

Comment: I'll add the computation in my answer. Your notation is problematic and that's the reason that you get stuck, this is a computation that is definitely easy enough for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't seen it though

Comment: @Chengdu see it

Comment: Thanks I see it now. However, I didn't show the first two axioms with summations should I do that as well or is it sufficient to do as I have done already with the first two axioms?

Comment: @chengdu what are you referring to? I cant understand what you mean

Comment: What I mean is that to show the third axiom of a *-algebra you use the summation notation, whereas I only use the symbols to show the first two axioms. Should I use the summation notation as well to show the first two axioms like you did to show the third axiom?

Comment: @chengdu yes, the other notation is not even specified

Comment: So instead of doing what I did before to show the other two axioms I should do it in this way?:  $(x^{*})^{*} = (\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \overline{x_{-n}})^{*} = (\sum_{n} x_{n})^{*} = (\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \overline{x_{-n}}) = (\sum_{n} x_{n}) = x$                                  and $(ax+by)^{*} = (a \sum_{n} x_{n} + b \sum_{m} y_{m})^{*} = (\overline{a} \sum_{n} \overline{x_{-n}} + \overline{b} \sum_{m} \overline{y_{-m}}) = \overline{a} x^{*} + \overline{b} y^{*}$ ?

Comment: @Chengdu no, why do you use these sums? where do they come from? summation occurs in the definition of the product. I meant you should use the sequence notation, just look through the definitions

Comment: do you mind showing me just one of them, then I can try to do the other one on my own once I get accustomed to the notation

Comment: @Chengdu $x=(x_n)$, so $x^*=(\bar{x}_{-n})_n$, so $(x^*)^*=(\bar{\bar{x}}_{-(-n)})_n=(x_n)_n=x$.